# How to save installed gems in Jenkins installed with Docker?

Tags: ruby, docker, jenkins, bundler

Every time the job I made in Jenkins run, it installs ALL the gems in the Gemfile.

It seems that the installed gems are not kept. How to keep it?

My job:

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'ruby:2.5.5' } }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'ruby --version'
                sh 'bundle install --jobs 5'
                sh 'bundle exec rspec'
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Jenkins: `jenkinsci/blueocean`

Comment: You need to build a custom image with your gems inside.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the intended outcome. As Docker is a transient container, the expectation is you should rebuild `bundle` from scratch each time.